# Split a string with dot as delimiter and only when substring starts with capital letter only

Tags: python

For example, if I have:

The fox is running. The cat is drinking. The phone runs on Android 4.3

Then the split ones are:

1. The fox is running
2. The cat is drinking
3. The phone runs on Android 4.3

I tried with `re.sub(r'[.\s+\W]+', '#', s)` , but it ends up in replacing any space with a #.

And with `s.split('. ')` , i can only solve half of the problem (except multiple spaces after dot and starts with a capital letter)

Comment: you need to show your efforts

Comment: Updated what I have so far

Comment: how about the  case `The fox is running. Look, the cat jumped! The phone runs on Android 4.3, the phones - on iOS.` ?

Comment: Then there should be 2 substrings [The fox is running,Look, the cat jumped! The phone runs on Android 4.3, the phones - on iOS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as you can guarantee sentences will start with capital letters, you can use a lookahead for `[A-Z]`. You'll probably also want to split with the whitespace as well, which you can do by including `\s*?` in the split:

```
import re
s = 'The fox is running. The cat is drinking. The phone runs on Android 4.3. How man days are left this month'

re.split(r'\.\s*?(?=[A-Z])', s)
```

**Results:**

```
['The fox is running',
 'The cat is drinking',
 'The phone runs on Android 4.3',
 'How man days are left this month']
```